# How to expand VSCode's Interactive Terminal's text font

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been working on a bunch of different projects in VSCode and just to clear up some space on my desktop I decided to quit all VSCode applications. Upon reopening it, the Interactive Terminal's text too small to read. I know you can just launch terminal and execute the same command but out of convince's sake I want to be able to increase the size of it again. [Example of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY28i.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the terminal display settings with [this configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-display-settings) in your settings.json.

Comment: I apologize for getting back so late, I've tried to do the within the JSON file but instead of increasing the size of the characters it simply increases the size of the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

I saw your photo, and it looks like there is some minor problem. Just reload your window - Command + R on macOS, or select Developer: Reload Window after opening the command palette. That should work.

Comment: I've tried doing the Command + R on VSCode but instead of zooming into the terminal, it zooms on the rest of the file while at the same leaving the text of there terminal still tiny. I tried using Developer: Reload Window but the text remains the same.

Comment: Did you try selecting **Developer: Reload Window** after opening the command palette?